# PostgreSQL Hibernate-types Data conversion error related to JSONB

Tags: string, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jsonb

Since hibernate does not natively support JSONB, I have implemented custom type. I can read data from table ad_my_table without a problem. However, when writing I am getting data conversion error. I also tried using 3rd party solutions like the "hibernate-types" library but got the same error.

**MyTable Entity class**:

```
import com.sample.console.backend.dao.entity.JsonbUserType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ad_my_table")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonbUserType.class)
public class CustomClientEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_table_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_id_seq", sequenceName = "ad_my_table_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "config", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private String config;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFileName()
    {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getConfig()
    {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(String config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

**JsonbUserType.class implementing UserType**:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class JsonbUserType implements UserType {

   public static final String JSONB_TYPE = "jsonb";

   @Override
   public Class<String> returnedClass() {
       return String.class;
   }

   @Override
   public int[] sqlTypes() {
       return new int[]{ Types.JAVA_OBJECT };
   }

   @Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

       if (names.length <= 0) { return null; }

       final String dbData = rs.getString(names[0]);

       String result = null;

       if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(dbData)) {
           String json = dbData.startsWith("\"") ? dbData.substring(1, dbData.length() - 1) : dbData;
           result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(json);
       }

       return result;
   }

   @Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
           throws HibernateException, SQLException {

       if (value instanceof String && StringUtils.isNotBlank((String)value))
       {
           PGobject pgObject = new PGobject();
           pgObject.setType(JSONB_TYPE);
           pgObject.setValue((String)value);
           st.setObject(index, pgObject, Types.OTHER);
       }
       else {
           st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
       return value;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isMutable() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

       if(x == null) { return y == null; }

       return x.equals(y);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
       assert (x != null);
       return x.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
       return this.deepCopy( cached);
   }

   @Override
   public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
       return (String)this.deepCopy( value);
   }

   @Override
   public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
       return original;
   }
}
```

**CustomPostgreSQLDialect.class extending PostgreSQL10Dialect**:

```
import com.sample.console.backend.dao.entity.JsonbUserType;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect
{
    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, JsonbUserType.JSONB_TYPE);
    }
}
```

**The error I am getting**:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "X'aced000...74227d' (AD_MY_TABLE: ""CONFIG"" ""JSONB"")"; SQL statement: insert into ad_my_table (config, filename, id) values (?, ?, ?) [22018-200]

Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Data conversion error converting "OTHER to JSON" [22018-200]
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?  I am having the same issue.
It works when actually running against Postgres, but not against H2.

Instead of using a custom dialect to register the JSONB support I've used a connection string that creates a JSONB type as JSON (to work around the H2 JSON == Postgres JSONB issue), but I still have the same problem:  
    
`jdbc:h2:mem:<table>;INIT=create domain if not exists JSONB as JSON`

Comment: In my case, importing hibernate-types worked for me. I may have had a different issue because as you said, it didn't solve your problem.  
`<dependency>`  
    `<groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>`  
    `<artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>`  
`</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Use connect string that creates Jsonb types as clob, `jdbc:h2:mem:<table>;INIT=create domain if not exists jsonb as CLOB;`. This works fine as along as you define your field as String in your Entity. If you define your field in Entity as your CustomJson Object then it only supports DB read operations.

This works:

```
@Column(name = "config", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private String config;
```

This doesn't supports read operations

```
@Column(name = "config", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private MyJsonObject config;
```